# listing users filtered by whether they have posted content or not

Tags: 6, views

I've been fiddling with the filters in views but none of the filters seem to work on if they posted content or not.

Is custom code necessary for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Relationships instead? **User:Nodes authored** might be what you are looking for.